# Add user login to select content

Tags: login

We have a customer training service module in (PowerPoint slide show format) for select employees. It has to be accessible from a web page with a login. What is the simplest way to accomplish the login? I am thinking it might be best to make the page separate from the corporate site (like it's own mini site) and use a limited access login through EE.

We have a corporate EE website and do not use any vistor login.

I'm a technically challenged designer and EE newbie responsible for expansion, updating content and making some changes to the design of our corporate site. Thank  you!

Comment: Laura's SOLUTION:                                         
Read a post that mentioned a 'password protected EE template'and it sparked me to try the following:                   
(1) Created a new site template called 'login-required'
(2) Adjusted the Member 'Access' settings and enabled HTTP Authentication (When on, users from allowed groups have to login to view the template)
(3) Created a new entry with my content and a new category called 'login-required'                         
<p>It appears to be working fine. I'm still open to hear of other methods if any are known and shared. Thanks!

Comment: Please post this as an answer instead of a comment...